# How can I rotate the file I'm writing to in node.js?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I'm writing records to a file in node.js and I need to rotate the file with a new one every so many lines or after a duration but I can't lose any lines in the process. If I try with fs.createWriteStream to create a new stream I end up losing lines by overwriting the old stream. Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: the the records some kind of logs?

Comment: The records are csv format to be shipped to a database in bulk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overwrite the old stream.  Create the new stream as a separate resource.

```
var activestream;

function startup() {
    activestream = fs.createWriteStream('path');
}

function record(line) {
    activestream.write(line);
}

function rotate() {
    var newstream = fs.createWriteStream('path2');
    activestream.end();
    activestream = newstream;
}
```

... something like that should work.  Obviously you'll have to figure out how to manage the paths.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give an unconventional answer here.

You can consider a ready made library like [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) which comes with well tested functionality to do exactly what you want. Given it's meant to write logs, but you can write your csv entries too just as easily.

Another big advantage of using winston is it supports multiple transports, so you can write not only to files and rotate them you can also write to other media MongoDB and few others.

It also does stuff like conditional writing and you can define custom 'log-level' to write different functional records to your file.

I recommend you check it out before cooking your own solution.

Comment: Yeah I considered doing this before but I would rather have more flexibility in the naming convention. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing your own stream manager similar to Jason's, but instead of ending the stream when rotate is requested, let the write finish, pause the stream, rotate the file, then resume the stream.  Only one stream per file should be required and you shouldn't need to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this solution and found npm module [rotating-file-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream) very useful and simple to use. It is available with different options. Here is basic usage:

```js
const rfs = require("rotating-file-stream");
const stream = rfs.createStream("file.log", {
  size: "10M", // rotate every 10 MegaBytes written
  interval: "1d", // rotate daily
  compress: "gzip" // compress rotated files
});
```

There is another popular npm module [file-stream-rotator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-stream-rotator), but I found the other one simple and flexible. Choose as per your requirement.